# Starting flatpak inside WSL 2, using X Server on host crashes org.gnome.Epiphany.Devel

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, debian, flatpak, epiphany

Well, I as the title says I have installed flatpak, and org.gnome.Epiphany.Devel inside my WSL 2, and I the app crashes everytime I open it.

Below is the bash script I wrote trying to summarize the actions I have taken to start the Epiphany Browser:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#WSL_HOST VAR
export WSL_WINDOWS_HOST=`cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
export DISPLAY=$WSL_WINDOWS_HOST":0"

echo "Starting DBUS Service...";
sudo service dbus start

eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)
sudo usermod -a -G messagebus $USER

# Config Flatpak
flatpak --user config --set languages 'en'

# Start Epiphany Devel using Flatpak
flatpak run --verbose  --env=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS org.gnome.Epiphany.Devel
```

The error is:

```
(epiphany:2): epiphany-WARNING **: 13:01:43.663: Web process crashed                                                    flatpak-spawn: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input                                                                Try "flatpak-spawn --help" for more information.
```

Comment: Your tags & question make little sense to me; it's a debian/ubuntu workflow/packaging issue? in your tags & yet is related to flatpak (*which isn't a packaging format used by Debian/Ubuntu in their workflow*) yet WSL related? when WSL doesn't apply either.  What OS/release and how does the workflow issue relate? flatpak? given Debian & Ubuntu workflow involves *deb* packaging only.

Comment: @guiverc I will update my question with all the Debian and WSL information I have installed. Although I think that Epiphany Browser does not have a deb package?

Comment: sorry I didn't know that epiphany-browser had a package. This is why you don't ask CHATGTP. Thanks a lot @guiverc